# C++ coroutines and ANDROID flag

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, c++-coroutine

I'm trying to integrate a boost project using asio and coroutines on android. I use `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fcoroutines-ts")` on the CMakeLists.txt file (c++17 is used). When i set this flag the ANDROID macro becomes undefined. If i add -DANDROID then the coroutines get disabled. Are this two flags incompatible? Can i use c++ coroutines on Android with NDK?

Comment: A set command overwrites old values with new one. Correct usage for appending new flags is set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}" "-fcoroutines-ts"). Btw, android ndk ver 23.1 supports c++20 incompletly and you can not use c++ coroutines yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` you're overwriting the original value, which likely was set to include `-DANDROID` by the toolchain file you're using or CMake directly. There are two possibilities here:

- You can use `add_compile_options("-fcoroutines-ts")` instead, this will add the flag to all targets defined afterwards
- If only a single target makes use of coroutines you can also set it via `target_compile_options(<target> PUBLIC "-fcoroutines-ts")` or `target_compile_options(<target> PRIVATE "-fcoroutines-ts")` depending on whether you're using coroutines in public headers of that target (choose PUBLIC) or only in the implementation (choose PRIVATE).